# Power series expansion of $f(x)=\frac{x}{2x^2+1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I was requested to find a series representation of $$f(x)=\frac{x}{2x^2+1}$$

and its convergence radius. I attempted a solution but it is wrong according to online calculators, and I can't find my mistake.

My approach was the standard procedure of rewriting $f(x)$ as $\frac{1}{1-u}$ where $u$ is a function of $x$, and using the fact that $\frac{1}{1-u}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty u^n $. I noticed that

$$f(x)=\frac{x}{2x^2+1} = x \cdot \frac{1}{1-(-2x^2)} = x \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-2x^2)^n = x\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-2)^n (x^2)^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-2)^n (x^2)^{n+1}$$

The expansion I get is therefore $f(x) = \frac{x}{2x^2+1}=x^2 - 2x^4 + 4x^6-8x^8+...$ with a convergence radius of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

As stated earlier, this does not match with the results I get from automated computations, and yet I can't find an error in my logic. I only started learning power series a couple of hours ago, so I must be clearly missing something. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $x(x^2)^n=x^{2n+1}\ne(x^2)^{n+1}=x^{2n+2}$

Comment: Just some algebra errors. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that\begin{align}x\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-2)^n(x^2)^n&=x\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-2)^nx^{2n}\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-2)^nx^{2n+1},\end{align}and therefore the answer is $x-2x^3+4x^5-8x^7+\cdots$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $x - 2x^3 + 4x^5-...$? For $n=2$ we have $2n+1 = 5$.  That aside, which probably is just a typo, the only reason I don't mark your answer as correct is that the site asks me to wait 5 minutes. I'll do it in a bit, and thank you so much!

Comment: It was a typo. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

*Another way to do it*

$$f(x)=\frac{x}{2x^2+1}\quad \implies \int f(x)\,dx=\frac{1}{4} \log \left(1+2 x^2\right)$$ Let $t=2x^2$

$$\log(1+t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \frac {t^n}n$$

$$\frac{1}{4} \log \left(1+2 x^2\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \frac {2^{n-2}}n x^{2n}$$

Now, differentiate
$$f(x)=\frac{x}{2x^2+1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} 2^{n-1} x^{2 n-1}$$